# ASP.NET 6 JWT Bearer Authentication fails with 401 including the message that the signature key was not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, keycloak

My goal is to include JWT Bearer authentication into my ASP.NET 6 application. The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` is what I use as a package.

According to my understanding, it is irrelevant from which Provider I use an accessToken. What matters most is that the validation is accurate.

`Keycloak` is what I use in the background. I've previously created an user account there. I am using his accessToken in the Authorization header to address one of my routes. I am receiving a `401 error`. I'm afraid I don't know why right now.

***www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The signature key was not found"***

My access token has the following properties

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "xxxx"
}

{
  "exp":xxx,
  "iat": xxx,
  "jti": "xxx",
  "iss": "http://localhostxxx",
  "sub": "cxxx",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "account xxx",
  "nonce": "bxxxx",
  "session_state": "2x",
  "acr": "0",
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "sid": "2xxxx",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "user",
  "preferred_username": "user",
  "given_name": "user",
  "family_name": "usser",
  "email": "user@web.de"
}
```

Thats my corresponding code

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        o.Authority = "account xxx"; // In my case account xxx (jwt.azp)
        o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = "http://localhostxxx" //  jwt.iss propertie,
            IssuerSigningKey =
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxxx")) //  jwt.iss kid propertie,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            RequireAudience = false, 
            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            RequireSignedTokens = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ValidateTokenReplay = false,
            ValidateActor = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
        };
    });
```

I have the feeling that the error lies with the `options.Authority`

Do I have `Keycloak` set up incorrectly? I am getting the most important properties from that URL (`Keycloak` specific): `http://localhost:xxx/realms/xxx/protocol/openid-connect/certs`.Personally I don't think `Keycloak` has anything to do with it

Comment: Keycloak issues a token that is signed with RS256, which is an asymmetric algorithm (signed with the private key, verification with the public key).  The key is identified by the key Id (kid) in the header of the token. But you are loading a symmetric key here: `IssuerSigningKey =  new SymmetricSecurityKey(...)`.

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly I did wrong? A code example would be appreciated.

Comment: @jps should I use `JsonWebKey`?